# Book recommendation - historical / biographrical take on geology?

Tags: geology, reference-request, history

I am looking for a book (and/or show) that tackles geology on a popular science level from a historical perspective with biographical components of the scientists / discoverers involved in moving the field forward.

I have come across these types of works for other fields - e.g., [The Disappearing Spoon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0316051632) for chemistry, and several episodes of Cosmos have this kind of narrative form for physics and astronomy. They are useful because they are simple, engaging, and give an idea of questions that were being asked over time and how they were resolved. So they can be nice for gaining a broad overview of a subject if you're a novice, which I am.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Thanks for any help!